# Вызов скрипта с ключом -h или -help

Tags: python

Обыскал весь интернет, посмотрел в 2 книжках(одни магические слова), никак не могу понять как вызвать скрипт с этими ключами...Подскажите пожалуйста...

Comment: python script.py -h
?

Comment: да пробовал, что то никак как бы

Comment: Это Ваш скрипт или сторонний?

Comment: Скрипт в студию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import getopt
import sys

def main():
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'h', ['help'])
    except getopt.GetoptError, err:
        print str(err) # print "option -a not recognized"
        sys.exit(2)

    for o, a in opts:
        if o in ('-h', '--help'):
            print """Usage: python scrypt.py [OPTION] ...

  -h, --help                      display this help and exit

Report bugs to <mail@mail.com>
"""
            sys.exit()
        else:
            assert False, 'unhandled option'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Т.е. читать про getopt: http://docs.python.org/library/getopt.html

Answer (score 2):

Ваш скрипт как-то обрабатывает опцию "-h" ?

Если нет, то ничего и не произойдет. Самое простое решение это:

```
import sys
#.......
#в точке входа
if ( "-h" in sys.argv[1:] ) : #обрабатываем опцию "-h"
```

Если такого функционала недостаточно, то смотрите в сторону модуля argparse, это модуль для парсинга списка параметров, с которыми запущен скрипт.

Comment: Спасибо, сделал вот так:

    try:
        if ("-h" in sys.argv[1:]):
            'ok'
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        print 'This is the programm allow you accomplish search necessary airport'

Но при запуске не из командной строки он все равно печатает этот текст, как это можно исправить? =)

Comment: import sys есть? лучше в except обрабатывать конкретное исключение, чтобы не пропустить не явные ошибки

Comment: сис есть! я понял почему, потому что стоит файнали и после него он по любому выполнит принт...)